# Unable to draw Unicode characters with Python's PyCDC.DrawText()

Tags: python, winapi, unicode, pywin32

I'm trying to draw Unicode characters using PyCDC.DrawText(), but it seems to draw two ASCII characters instead. For example, when trying to draw 'Я' (\u042F), I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh9RJ.png

My string is defined as a Unicode string:

```
text = u'Я'
```

And the file starts with:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

I also tried printing the string (to the console) and it comes out fine, so the problem is probably lying within the implementation of DrawText().

Thanks!

Comment: what does the documentation of PyCDC.DrawText say? (I'm not an expert, but considering you don't get an exception, maybe the font doesn't support unicode?)

Comment: Doesn't say anything about Unicode.

Comment: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/PyCDC__DrawText_meth.html

Comment: Oh, and I'm using all the fonts on my computer, so it's not specific :)

Comment: How is this represented in your source file?  The proper UTF-8 encoding of that character should be the two bytes \xD0 \xAF.  (What do these codes map to in your current code page?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output Unicode text on Windows you need to encode it in UTF-16 and call the wide character version of the [`DrawText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [`TextOut()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145133%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 functions. In case you aren't familiar, the Windows API is natively UTF-16 and has parallel 8 bit ANSI versions for legacy support.

I know nothing of the Win32 wrapper you are using but rather suspect that `PyCDC.DrawText()` is calling the ANSI version of whichever one of these Win32 functions is doing the work.  Your solution will likely involve finding a way to invoke `DrawTextW()` or `TextOutW()`. You could do it with ctypes, and these functions must surely be available through PyWin32 also.

However, I would probably opt for something higher level, like PyQt.

Comment: Thanks David. I came to a similar conclusion myself: PyQt does it with less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

David: 'these functions must surely be available through PyWin32 ' actually, they are not.

After dozens of hours of searching, trying to figure out where within `win32ui`, `win32gui`, etc. there might be a hidden `TextOutW`, writing my own C extension that had other flaws so couldn't use it, writing an external prog. called from within python only to find out that `HDC` handles cannot be transfered to other processes, I have finally stumbled upon this single-line elegant pre-programmed solution, based on `ctypes` as suggested above:

1. you need the `TextOutW` or similar function as you were used to from windows gdi c. Although there is a function called `win32gdi.DrawTextW` which works exactly like the windows counterpart, yet sometimes you need to specifically use e.g. `TextOut`, `ExtTextOut` etc., which are not available in the unicode `W`-suffixed versions in `pywin32`'s `win32gdi`
2. to achieve this, instead of using the limited `win32gui` functions, use `windll.gdi32.TextOutW` available from `ctypes`:

   ```
   from ctypes import *
   import win32gdi

   # init HDC
   # set hdc to something like 
   hdc = win32gdi.CreateDC(print_processor, printername, devmode)

   # here comes the ctypes function that does your deal
   text = u'Working! \u4e00\u4e01'
   windll.gdi32.TextOutW(hdc, x, y, text, len(text))

   # ... continue your prog ...
   ```

Have fun with this